# Resource failed: not found (404). Munit 4

Tags: mule, munit

I am getting resource not found error when running multiple munit (version 4) test cases from one file. But if run then individually they run fine.

Any help is much appriciated.

**HTTP Config:**

`<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Munit_configuration" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="c3f254ef-d670-4cae-81dd-37eca8de05e8" basePath="/leads/v1" >
        <http:request-connection host="localhost" port="8081" />
    </http:request-config>`

**Error:**

org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: HTTP PUT on resource 'http://localhost:8081/leads/v1/XXX' failed: not found (404).

Comment: You should share the flow config as well, since the request is being sent to an HTTP listener and such a 404 probably means that the flow that's suppose to handle it has not been started.

Answer (score 0):

MUnit does not actually run your service. It creates special environment to run flows for testing.

If you want to test real server then you have o run it separately and then later run MUnit in the separate environment.

IMHO MUnit is designed to test units - flows, subflows, transformations. It was not designed to test servers.